# Autologin in VB NET failed

Tags: vb.net, automation, web-controls

Hello I am working on autologin for page, I am using WebBrowser control. I have this code which sets the value of DOM elements with the values found in my form controls, TextBox1 and TextBox2:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text.ToString())
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text.ToString())
```

It fill the elements with text from TextBoxes, but if i hit "Log IN" button, it says that user does not exist or the password is bad.

These 2 inputs I'm trying to fill :

```
<input type="email" name="email" tabindex="0" value="">
<input type="password" name="password" tabindex="0" value="">
```

I also tried to load the values using a RichTextBox control and they are same so I don't really know where is the problem. If I try to log in manually, all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The DOM elements do not have an ID attribute, but they do have name attributes set. This makes it a bit more difficult in that you will need to query the document's elements a bit differently, but it is still achievable. Try the following:

```
Dim emailInput As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("email").FirstOrDefault()
Dim passwordInput As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("password").FirstOrDefault()

If (emailInput IsNot Nothing) Then
    emailInput.SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
End If
if (passwordInput IsNot Nothing) Then
    passwordInput.SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text)
End If
```

What this code does is it tries to get the first input element named email as well as the first input element named password. If the element was found, then it sets the attribute to the respective TextBox text.

You'll noticed that I removed the `.ToString()` from the Text property. This is because the Text property returns a String and so what you were doing was converting a String... into a String.

**Update**

My apologies, I did not realize that the HtmlElementCollection doesn't support FirstOrDefault. You'll need to change the code slightly to:

```
Dim emailInputs As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("email")
Dim passwordInputs As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("password")
If (emailInputs.Count() > 0) Then
    Dim emailInput As HtmlElement = emailInputs.Item(0)
    emailInput.SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
End If
If (passwordInputs.Count() > 0) Then
    Dim passwordInput As HtmlElement = emailInputs.Item(0)
    passwordInput.SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text)
End If
```

Comment: I tried it and I´ve got this errors : Error   BC30456 'GetElementByTagName' is not a member of 'HtmlDocument'.

Error   BC30020 'Is' operator does not accept operands of type 'Integer'. Operands must be reference or nullable types.

Comment: @RadoPagacik What version of the .NET framework are you targeting?

Comment: @RadoPagacik take a look at my update code, I free type my code and there were typos. GetElementByTagName should have been GetElementsByTagName and `Is Not Nothing` should have been `IsNot Nothing`.

Comment: I noticed. I´ve got just this now: 'FirstOrDefault' is not a member of 'HtmlElementCollection'.

Comment: @RadoPagacik if LINQ is supported on the HtmlElementCollection then you'll need to use a conditional statement to check the Count (if greater than 0) and then get the element by specifying the item. I'll update my answer.